# iframe src url changing the parent url unintentionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

We are making calls from our website (www.example.com) to api server (api.example.com) via iframe.

When we are making calls, the iframe source url changes the parent window url to iframe source url. Given below is the iframe code:

```
<iframe onload="iframeManager.tempIframeCallback()" id="xd_iframe" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" tabindex="0" name="xd_iframe" style="position:absolute;top:-9999em;width:10px;height:10px;" src= "{{html on api server}}">
        </iframe>
```

Given below is the html on api server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <title>xyz</title>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.domain='example.com';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Reference: http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/

Comment: why are you using iframes? why not do an ajax call to load the page/data?

Answer (score 1):

The article you are referring to was written in 2005! Now a days, most modern browsers support CORS which allow you to do cross origin AJAX cleanly provided the server allows it. Here is one blog post explaining how: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/